# Parallel computations with fast randomness and purity?

Tags: haskell, random, parallel-processing

My goal is to parallelize a computation using `parMap` from the [parallel package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel), but I'd also like to add a bit of randomness to my sampling function.

Without the randomness my calculation is simply some number crunching and so it's pure and I could use `parMap`. In order to get good results, I need to take multiple samples at each step and average the results. The sampling needs to be randomized.

One solution might be to use the [random package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random), call `randoms` and then consume that list during the computation (by passing the pure lazy list to the computation I would keep it pure). Unfortunately, that's a very slow random number generator and I need a lot of random numbers so I would prefer to use either [mwc-random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random) or [mersenne-random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random) (although, I don't think mersenne-random is still maintained).

Is it safe to use something like `unsafePerformIO` with mwc-random to write a function like `randoms`? Something like this:

```
randomsMWC :: Variate a => GenST s -> [a]
randomsMWC g = unsafePerformIO $ unsafeSTToIO $ randomsMWC' g
  where
  randomsMWC' g = do
    a  <- uniform g
    as <- unsafeInterleaveST $ randomsMWC' g
    return (a : as)
```

Do I need to instead reach for a [parallel number generator](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/fast-high-quality-parallel-random-number/229625477)? Or do I need to bite the bullet and admit that my algorithm is simply not pure without using the slow random package?

Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: mersenne-random-pure64 is both fast and allows multiple generators - so you can have one per thread.

Comment: @DonStewart Multiple generators is entirely useless for parallel haskell. There's no facility for using thread-specific resources from parallel code, and there shouldn't be - it would introduce non-determinism. This is really a hard problem.

Comment: Carl - not so. You can duplicate random gens in a data parallel fashion, avoiding the contention on a shared resource. Think of a tree-structured reduction, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If having a single threaded source of randomness isn't a problem for performance, you can get a pure wrapper around mwc-random

```
import Control.Monad.ST.Lazy
import Control.Monad
import System.Random.MWC

rList :: Variate a => Seed -> [a]
rList s = runST $ do
  g <- strictToLazyST $ restore s
  advance g

advance :: Variate a => Gen s -> ST s [a]
advance g = do
  x <- strictToLazyST $ uniform g
  xs <- x `seq` advance g
  return (x:xs)
```

here `rList` takes a seed, and then lazily produces an infinite stream of lazy numbers deterministically.  I am not sure that `strictToLazyST` is really safe, but no one seems to object to it.  I have not done any benchmarking, but I suspect this is pretty fast.  I assume that `mwc-random` is thread safe because of the explit data flow encoded with the generator, and that it can be used in the `ST` monad.  Inviting someone to use the hack above.  I don't think the `seq` is necessary, but it makes me less suspicous of `strictToLazyST` that I know I have deterministic evaluation order (and it is still lazy enough to work).

You still need randomness (that is `IO`) somewhere to generate a real random seed, but this should let you keep most of the code pure, and let you store the seed to file or reuse it when necessary.

GHCi:

```
λ: gen <- create
λ: x <- save gen
λ: drop 1 $ take 10 $ rList x :: [Int]
[4443157817804305558,-6283633474236987377,3602072957429409483,
 -5035101780705339502,-925260411398682800,423158235494603307,
 -6981326876987356147,490540715145304360,-8184987036354194323]
```

Answer (score 7):

I have a not quite release-ready package `hsrandom123` on [Github](https://github.com/kosmikus/hsrandom123) that might be helpful here. I have started implementing this package in order to have a suitable RNG for parallel computations available. It reimplements the Philox and Threefry RNGs from [the `random123` C library](http://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/) (there's a paper describing the ideas there, too).

There's a reason my library is unreleased, though: while the actual RNG implementation is done and seems to produce the same results as the C version, I've been undecided what Haskell interface to use, and the library is hardly documented. Feel free to contact me if you need more info or help using it, though.

Comment: Interesting. If it's unreleased, I don't think I want to use it but I do look forward to trying it out in the future.

Comment: Funnily enough, I've been working on a Haskell port of Random123 too recently, although I swear I did a google search beforehand and could not find any other Haskell implementations. Mine can be found at github.com/Manticore/haskell-random123, and also as Random123 on Hackage (I'm prepared to give up the Hackage entry though, since you clearly have the priority).

Comment: Ah, too bad that we didn't coordinate work. My version is on github for some time, but as it's not on Hackage yet, I guess it's easy to overlook. I'll have a look at your version soon. I think I'll stick with the `hsrandom123` name. If we come to a clear agreement what the differences are, we should probably include them in the documentation though so that users can make an informed choice.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that *mersenne-random* isn't thread safe, so using any `unsafe...` and parallelization will lead you to problems with calling it from multiple threads. (See also the [GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html) Section 8.2.4.1.)

Functions that need randomness aren't pure, they need some source of randomness, which is either external ([hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) - like a device sampling noise) and hence bound to `IO`, or pseudorandom, which needs to keep some state during the computation. Either way they can't be pure Haskell functions.

I'd start with separating your requirements to a specific monad type class, for example something like

```
class Monad m => MonadParRand m where
    random      :: MTRandom a => m a
    parSequence :: [m a] -> m [a]
```

which will allow you to write your main code without being bound to a specific implementation. Or if you're feeling bold you could use [monad-parallel](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-parallel/0.5.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Parallel.html) and define something like

```
class MonadParallel m => MonadParRand m where
    random      :: MTRandom a => m a
```

Now the tricky part is how to define both `random` and `parSequence` (or `MonadParallel`'s [`bindM2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-parallel/0.5.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Parallel.html#v:bindM2)) *and* making it fast. Since you're in control of `bindM2`, you can manage how threads are spawned and what state they keep. So you can bind a buffer to each thread from which it draws randomized numbers. If the buffer is empty, it makes a synchronized calls to mersenne-random (or another `IO`-based number generator), fills the buffer and proceeds.

(If you implement something like that, it'd be very nice to make a standalone library from that.)

---

Note that `randoms` from mersenne-random already uses `unsafeInterleaveIO` to produce a lazy list, but I'd say the list is meant to be consumed only from a single thread. And it has also room for improvements. It uses `unsafeInterleaveIO` and it has some overhead, as noted in [its comment](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mersenne-random/1.0.0.1/doc/html/src/System-Random-Mersenne.html#line-166):

> There are real overheads here. Consider eagerly filling chunks and extracting elements piecewise.

Comment: A function that takes a PRNG and returns a PRNG along with something else is still quite pure.

Comment: @Carl I understand, it's just about the terminology. I used _pure_ in the sense that _a function producing a value of type `a` is pure if it's type is `a`_. You used it probably in the sense that _a function producing a value of type `a` is pure if it doesn't involve `IO`_. A fun and inspiring post about the meaning of _pure_ is Conal Elliots [The C language is purely functional](http://conal.net/blog/posts/the-c-language-is-purely-functional).

Comment: No, I'm using it in the sense "The outputs are determined by only the inputs." That's the actual useful meaning of "pure".

Comment: @Carl Indeed this is a sensible definition, I'd just like to note that _all_ Haskell functions are pure in this sense (and this is why we like Haskell so much), no matter whether they involve `IO` or not. For example `getLine` is a true constant - it has no side effects, evaluating it like in `const () $! getLine` does nothing. Its output is a constant value that describes an action that does something _when executed_ by a Haskell runtime, but not when the function is evaluated. We only perceive it as "impure" because we usually focus on what it does when executed.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness of answers, let me explain what I'm doing at the moment to solve this problem.

Instead of trying to make the computation pure, I've opted for using the [async](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) package instead of [parallel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel).

If I decide to revise my current solution to be pure, I will first try the solution suggested by Philip JF, so I have marked his answer as the accepted one.

My next challenge is figuring out how to approximate optimal chunking of the work so that threading reduces the amount of time instead of making it take longer :)